# C# for loop skipping last item

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have the below `for` loop

```
int listCount = _itemCollection.Count;
//_itemCollection is of type SPListItemCollection  
for (int i=0;i<listCount;i++)
{
    var item = _itemCollection[i]; // just to prevent changes in all places inside the for loop
    if(item['expirydate']>today){
        item.delete();
        listCount--; //as I am removing 1 item, I am decrementing count
    }    
}
```

In this `for` loop, I am iterating through the items in `itemcollection` and deleting some of them. i.e item will be removed from `itemcollection` array and  so `itemcollection.count` will be reduced by 1

This is not deleting the 3rd item every time, when I have 3 items to delete

I am not sure what condition should be used for getting it right

Comment: Try `for (int i=listCount-1;i>=0;i--)`

Comment: This code won't compile (`foreach` only works on enumerable items). Is this your exact code?

Comment: foreach syntax itself is wrong

Comment: What data type is `_itemCollection`?

Comment: sorry that was for, not foreach
_itemcollection is an object array

Comment: what happen when you call `item.delete();`? does it removes from the _itemCollection? if not, it is not required to reduce `listCount--`

Comment: @S.Serp Yes you are right, it removes it from _itemcollection

Answer (score 2):

You should go in the reverse order as below and use `for` instead of `foreach` as below.

```
int listCount = _itemCollection.Count;
                    for (int i = listCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                     var item = _itemCollection[i]; // just to prevent changes in all places inside the for loop
                     if(item['expirydate'] > today){
                         item.delete();
                      }    
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
_itemCollection.RemoveAll(item => item['expirydate'] > today);
```

This removes all the items that matches the given condition.

To remove item from SPListItemCollection check this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.delete(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: SharePoint `SPListItemCollection`  does not have such `RemoveAll` method!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int listCount = _itemCollection.Count; 
    for (int i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
    {
        var item = _itemCollection[i];
        if(item [expirydate] > today)
        {
            _itemCollection.Remove(item);
            listCount--;
        }
    }
```

This may fulfill your want. Here you can directly use _itemCollection[i] instead of item.
I hope this may help you. Enjoy coding.

Comment: There is no function named Remove in SPListItemCollection. @vignesh do not upvote everything.

Comment: Thankyou! Prabu for pointing this out. I have checked the code before posting and it works fine. But I had used List not the SPListItemCollection. Sorry for the mistake. 
Thanks again.

Comment: However, does SPListItemCollection holds any function named RemoveAll? I am not sure. Please elaborate if possible.